# Converting Decode Substr Oracle query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-migration

I have a Oracle query that I'm trying to convert to SQL Server 2012 and am finding it hard to see how I achieve the same thing.

The SQL in question is:

```
SELECT decode( substr(a.Code, 1, 8), 'APP VARY', 'C', 'B') AS Value1
From tblA a
```

If I am understanding correctly, `DECODE` is the ORACLE way of doing `IIF` in SQL Server. So I'm thinking I can use something like:

```
Select IIF(SUBSTRING(a.Code,1,8)='APP VARY','C','B') as Value1
```

Does this look right?

Anyone have an idea how I can achieve the same thing in SQL Server?

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language, it doesn't have `decode`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - i have an Oracle query that has decode and runs with no issues. that same exact format

Comment: That's right, Oracle SQL has `decode`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson :) 99% of the time I'm in SSMS

Comment: Why not just use a ```CASE``` statement?

Comment: @koosh FYI SSMS is purely a client interface it is **not** the database engine. So you wouldn't normally tag SSMS unless the question is specifically about the SSMS UI. Normally you would tag SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments it would appear that a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression is what you want e.g.

```
case substring(a.Code, 1, 8) when 'APP VARY' then 'C' else 'B' end
```

Note: and replace `substr` with `substring`.

In fact the following, using `like` should accomplish the same thing and perform better:

```
case when a.Code like 'APP VARY%' then 'C' else 'B' end
```